# How do I exit if statement if the 1st input is wrong but the 2nd one is correct it displays an error message for the 1st one and accepts the 2nd one

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to make it so that when the user enters a password in the password textbox it checks its length and if it is less than 10 characters it displays an error message but it have you have a password that is 10 or more characters long it accepts the password and opens the game form. I have it so that it displays the error message but if the first attempt is incorrect all other attempts after even if they are 10 characters or longer it displays the error message when it shouldn't

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    PasswordRestrictions.Hide();

    if (NewPassword.Text.Length <= 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your password must be atleast 10characters long");
    }

    if (NewPassword.Text.Length >= 10)
    {
        this.Hide();
        var gameForm = new GameForm();
        gameForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        gameForm.Show();
    }
    
}
```

This is the code so far.

Comment: `if (NewPassword.Text.Length <= 10)` includes 10 characters passwordss

Comment: What @Cid is saying is that a `Length` of 10 will satisfy both `if` conditions. Consider getting the first one right and then using `else`. By the way, when testing your code, you should always include more that two test conditions. In you case, I'd text empty, short, length == 10 and long.

Comment: Title is TOO long.

Answer (score 0):

As the commentor mentioned, you are checking for <= 10, and then in the second `if`, >= 10. So if a user enters a password exactly 10 characters long, it'll execute both `if` blocks. Try changing the second `if` to an `else`.

Based on your note:

> I have it so that it displays the error message but if the first attempt is incorrect all other attempts after even if they are 10 characters or longer it displays the error message when it shouldn't

I can't see any obvious reason why `NewPassword.Text.Length` would report <= 10 if that wasn't the case. Can you place a breakpoint and inspect the value of the property?

It does seem likely that the logic in place to allow further attempts is faulty, and that is not shown here.

In any case, this would be my solution, given your variable names:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PasswordRestrictions.Hide(); // Re-enable on failure?
    if(NewPassword.Text.Length < 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your password must be at least 10 characters long");
        return;
    }
    this.Hide();
    var gameForm = new GameForm();
    gameForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
    gameForm.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is about what I would do:

```
private void btnSetPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if PW is longer than 10. Can also be replaced with <=, depending on what you want.
    if(txtPassword.Text.Length < 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Password too short!", "Error");
        lblPasswordRestrictions.Visible = true;
    }
    // Else will be executed if the if condition is false. I.e. if the PW is longer or exactly than 10.
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Password accepted.", "Ok!");
    }
}
```

Though, we do need a bit more info about your other stuff in order to help you.
Ideally, include at least a screenshot of the designer, or the CS code that get's generated behind it.

Also, I generally discourage the use of var. No big deal, but IMO better convention...

Comment: What's wrong with var?

Comment: @AndyWynn It's just not very declarative IMO. I think it looks easier to understand having the variable type right before the name. Also, while for class instantiation it is probably fine because you already have it after the new keyword then, it sets a bad habit and can lead to using it more often, even in other, ot so obvious situations, which then makes code harder to read and understand. I much prefer something like: List<int> list = new(); following the (somewhat) new C# syntax. You can also let VS' Code cleanup replace it for you, if you want the simplicity of writing it.

Comment: Ahh, I think we are on the same page. I was just interested. The only time I tend to use var is when I'm assigning a variable from a method return that may change to a compatable type. It can be more cumbersome to replace the type everywhere. I also used to use it for exceptionally long return types, but now we can alias these with using statements. The only other time is as you say, when dipping into framework projects and you are initialising with new.